# error Object of type ImageFieldFile is not JSON serializable in django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I'm trying to learn ajax in Django but when I ran this simple test I got this error and I can't find the reason, my Django version is 4.0

TypeError at /Customer/
Object of type ImageFieldFile is not JSON serializable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Customer/
Django Version: 4.0.1
Exception Type: TypeError

This is my js file code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#button_create_customer").click(function() {

    var serializData = $("#create_customer").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: $("create_customer").data('url'),
        data: serializData,
        dateType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
            $("#Customer_List_View").append('<tr role="row" class="odd" >\n' +
                '<td><a href="Profile/' + response.list.id + '/">' + response.list.Fullname + '</a></td>\n' +
                '<td>' + response.list.Phone + '</td>\n' +
                '<td>' + response.list.Address + '</td>\n' +
                '</tr>')
            const sText = 'ثبت مشخصات بیمار : "  ' + response.list.Fullname + '  " با موفقیت انجام گردید'
            handelAlert('success', sText)
            setTimeout(() => {
                alertBox.innerHTML = ""
            }, 3000)
        },
        error: function(error) {
            handelAlert('danger', 'خطا در ثبت');
            setTimeout(() => {
                alertBox.innerHTML = ""
            }, 3000);
        },
    })
    $("#create_customer")[0].reset();
});
```

});

> This is my Html file code:
>
> `<form id="create_customer" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" style="padding: 10px;"> {% csrf_token %}{{form|crispy}} <input type="submit" id="button_create_customer" value="ثبت" class="btn btn-success"> </form>`
>
> This is my View.py file code:

```
class List(View):
def get(self, request):
    list_customer = CustomerModel.objects.all()
    form = CustomerForm()
    return render(request, 'customer/index.html', context={
        'list_customer': list_customer,
        'form': form,
    })

def post(self, request):
    form = CustomerForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_customer = form.save()
        return JsonResponse({'list': model_to_dict(new_customer)}, status=200)
    else:
        return redirect('Customer_List')
```

Answer (score 1):

`HttpRequest.is_ajax()` method is deprecated from Django 3.1 and also removed in Django 4.0 as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/#features-removed-in-4-0)

Instead you should can inspect Accept header as per cleanup [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30997)

If you still want replicate old method functionality you can make your own base on [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/http/request.py#L260)

```
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of django `is_ajax` was removed. You can do it by self, using this code for example:

```py
def is_ajax(request):
    if request.META.get("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH") == "XMLHttpRequest":
        return True

    if request.content_type == "application/json":
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `Django` are you using?

From the release note of [3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/#id2)

> The HttpRequest.is_ajax() method is deprecated as it relied on a jQuery-specific way of signifying AJAX calls, while current usage tends to use the JavaScript Fetch API. Depending on your use case, you can either write your own AJAX detection method, or use the new HttpRequest.accepts() method if your code depends on the client Accept HTTP header

If you want to write your own `AJAX` detection method then you can check the request as

```
request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'.
```

> If you are writing your own AJAX detection method, request.is_ajax() can be reproduced exactly as request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest'

So you can create your custom `method` as

```
def is_ajax(request):
    return request.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

And use this method anywhere you want.